# Proper way to mux an HTTP server in Go that can handle non-HTTP protocols

Tags: http, go

I have built a router with extended logging capabilities using Go. It works properly for most use cases. However, it encounters problems when clients send non-standard HTTP messages on port 80.

To date, I have solved this by implementing my own version of ServeHTTP():

```
func (myproxy *MyProxy) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWtier, r *http.Request) {

  // Inspect headers
  // Determine if it is a custom protocol (ie: websockets, CONNECT requests)
  // Implement handlers for each time
}
```

In the event that I determine a request is a non-standard HTTP protocol, the request is played back to the original destination (via http.Request.Write()) and everyone is happy.

At least, most of the time. The problem arises with edge cases. Tivo clients do not send "Host" headers and appear to not like all kinds of other  standard things that Go does (such as capitalizing header names). The number of possible variations on this is endless so what I would very much like to do is to buffer the original request - exactly as it was sent to me without any modifications - and replay it back to the original destination server.

I could hack this by re-implementing net.Http.Server, but this seems like an extraordinarily difficult and brittle approach. Would I would prefer to do would be to somehow hook into net/http/http/server.go right around the point where it receives a connection, then wrap that in a spy wrapper that logs the request to a buffer.

```
func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {

        // Lots of listener code...

    c := srv.newConn(rw)
    c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return

        // I'd like to wrap c here and save the request for possible reply later.
    go c.serve(ctx)
}
```

https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=93229:93284#L2805

Edit: I have looked at httpUtil:DumpRequest but this slightly modifies the original request (changes case and order of headers). If it didn't do that, it would be an ideal solution.

https://godoc.org/net/http/httputil#DumpRequest

Is there a way to hook connections around this point before they are parsed by http.Request?

Comment: FWIW implementing HTTP servers is not overly difficult. I've done it 4 times in my life, twice for fun, once for a programming language that didn't have async I/O (Ferite, I implemented async I/O for my employer along with the async networking library) and once for an embedded project. The first time I did it after reading this: https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/ (the website says updated in 2012 but I'm fairly sure I did it before 2005)

Comment: Servers as endpoints are actually considerably easier than implementing transparent servers (proxies) which route requests for outside clients and servers out of your control. This code has been in use for about 18 months and handle most situations quite well. The above describes edge cases which are incredibly subtle and undetected in most implementations.

Comment: Actually I've also implemented proxies. I've even published one as open source (https://github.com/slebetman/typhos). Proxying is fairly easy. The tedious part is getting things like HTTP multipart right. Admittedly implementing a routing system is hard the first time around

Comment: If you need to handle non-HTTP traffic, you need to go a layer lower than the HTTP server in your application (i.e. to the Transport).

Comment: Sounds good. Can you please post a relevant solution if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of helping others, I wanted to answer my question. The approach I suggested above does in fact work and is the proper way to do this. In summary:

- Implement ListenAndServe()
- Wrap the incoming net.Conn in a TeeReader or other multiplexed connection wrapper
- Record the request
- Dial the original destination and connect with the inbound connection, replaying the original request if necessary.

A similar use case is required when upgrading connection requests for websockets servers. A nice writeup can be found here:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/million-websockets-and-go-cc58418460bb